# SQL: LIKE where condition specifying a letter followed by a number followed by anything else?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to write a WHERE condition in MS SQL Server that will grab rows that:

- begin with a specified letter
- then have a decimal
- then anything else

I basically have a table that contains postcodes and I want all postcodes that belong to Birmingham - B followed by a number. Some postcodes are in there that start B and then another letter which do not belong to Birmingham, so I can't simply use`LIKE 'B%'`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use LIKE 'B[0-9]%'. The "[0-9]" indicates any character in the range '0'-'9'.

Also bear in mind that (a) someone will have typed in an "O" instead of a "0" in some cases, and that there may be some international postcodes that also start with B and a number, so if you've got a reliable country field, you should check that, too :) Yes, I work with postcodes a lot :)

Comment: Birmingham, like most areas, doesn't have a '0' district, so 'B[1-9]%' would be more accurate (if a trifle pedantic). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom

Comment: @Mike Fair point! Although I notice in the database I have to hand, there are allegedly four "B0..." addresses in Birmingham, where I guess the users meant to type "B1...", so one may need to adjust one's pedantry levels depending on which particular errors need to be included :)

Comment: Using the data in the Ordnance Survey's Open Codepoint files, you could validate whether the postcode actually existed rather than simple validation on the formatting

Comment: Indeed, Open Codepoint is a lovely, and relatively recently-released resource, so it's definitely worth mentioning. You could then fairly easily geocode all your (valid) postcodes and have a query like "within ten miles of Birmingham City Centre" using Haversine, say. But it gets more complicated the odder your data is, with things like half-postcodes, or with stuff in the Channel Islands (which I believe are postcoded but aren't geocoded in Open Codepoint, last time I looked.)

Answer (score 2):

According to the Wikipedia article on the [B postcode area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_postcode_area):

- B39 is invalid
- B95 is Henley-in-Arden,
  Stratford-on-Avon -- would you
  consider Henley-in-Arden to "belong
  to Birmingham"? (maybe it is, I
  really don't know)

Perhaps safest to expand out the codes you consider to be Birmingham:

```
postcode LIKE 'B1 %'
OR postcode LIKE 'B2 %'
OR postcode LIKE 'B3 %'
...
OR postcode LIKE 'B10 %'
OR postcode LIKE 'B11 %'
OR postcode LIKE 'B12 %'
...
```

Those prefixes could of course be stored in a table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
Select * From PostCodes
Where PostCode Like 'B[0-9]%'
```

Comment: That will match a B, followed by any bunch of characters, followed by a number, followed by any bunch of characters, so I think it will match, for example, "BS1 6DF", a Bristol postcode, as well as the Birmingham postcodes.

Comment: @Matt - As soon as I posted I noticed a rogue % in there so I amended my answer straight away.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has regular expressions (REGEXP/RLIKE) built in. I think that you could add the functionality to others, such as SQL Server.

This would give you more precision, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM PostCodes WHERE PostCode RLIKE '^B[[:digit:]]{1,2}[:space:]'
```

This would also allow better matching of possible typos in the condition.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT postc FROM postcodes WHERE postc LIKE 'B[0-9]*%';
```

Something along these lines!

You could also do:

```
SELECT
    postc as ps,UPPER(SUBSTR(ps),1,1) as firstLetter,SUBSTR(ps,2,1) as secondNumber
FROM
    postcodes
WHERE
    firstLetter = 'B' AND secondNumber LIKE '[0-9]%'
```

Something along them lines.

Comment: -1 SQL doesn't work like that. Your LIKE predicate seems to contain two wildcard characters. The `firstletter` column correlation name in the `SELECT` clause cannot be used in `WHERE` clause.